# R.id cannot be resolved. Android.

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-xml

I have got the code:

```
package com.finalyearproject.cookmefood;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView recipes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.recipes);
    }
}
```

Which is giving me the error "id cannot be resolved".

I have tried cleaning the project but that results in me creating errors in file which currently are fine.

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">
                <ListView 
                    android:id="@+id/recipes"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:entries="@array.recipes"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated, where can I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@array.recipes` in the xml should be `@array/recipes`.
A simple typo like this will prevent your `R` class from building meaning you can't find any id's or other resources.
You should also make sure that you get the correct `R` as you are using both `android.R` and your `R`

Comment: I have made this change but im still getting the previous error.

Comment: @JamesMichaelLucas Right, check your other resources to make sure that they are all correct. It seems likely that you have another typo somewhere then.

Comment: I dont see how this could be an issue, as above I am accessing the 'R.layout.main'. Is it possible this error is coming from the layout in my XML? Im new with tabs and could the location of the linear layout be causing some error?

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean and rebuild your code. I don't know why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

***Use this com.finalyearproject.cookmefood.R.id.recipes.***